# Manually setting UpdateCommand or DeleteCommand for database in .net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, windows, datagridview

I am new to .net. I have created a table in SQL Server that shows up through dataGridView on Windows From. I wish to make the changes applicable directly on the data table on Windows Form. For that purpose I am using dataAdapter and dataCommandBuilder variables.

I am facing following issues:

1. I have to involve the primary key (that I don't want my user to see) in the table.
2. I wish to use a procedure to update or add any entry made in the table. 
   (procedure is in SQL Server).

My code:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda;
SqlCommandBuilder scb;
DataTable dt;

private void Refresh()
{
    string con = null;
    SqlConnection connect;
    con = @"Server =Hassan; Database =FBT; Integrated Security =SSPI;";
    connect = new SqlConnection(con);

    sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM Contact_Person", con);
    dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}

private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
    sda.Update(dt);
}

private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Refresh();
}
```

I think if there is any way I can manually set up the Update function, so I can direct it to the procedure I made, will solve my problems.

[Image attached below is my code, the numbers written in front of functions indicate their calling order]

Comment: what is your Stored Procedure ? include in the question

Comment: A SQL DataAdapter has four SQL Commands (Select, Insert, Delete, Update) and each command has a Command Text property to create a string query.

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView has several functionality to bind or unbound desired column, but since you need the primary key for update i suggest using `Visibility` see below:

after you took the query from database and you bound it to your DataGridView using its datasource aka `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;` turn the Primary Key field's visibility to false like below:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["PrimaryKey"].Visibility = false;
```

And Since i don't know your Stored Procedure, i can't get so specific but this is how you update your field.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server =Hassan; Database =FBT; Integrated Security =SSPI;"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure", conn))
{    
    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapt.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    //you should know whats the type of your primary key i assumed its int
    adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PrimaryKey", SqlDbType.Int)); 
    adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters["@PrimaryKey"].Value = PrimaryKey;

    //lets assume you are updating a Name which is string then
    adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
    adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters["@Name"].Value = Name;

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

**UPDATE**

Your SQL Stored Procedure would be like below:

```
CREATE Procedure ProcedureName
(
   @PrimaryKey Int,
   @Name varchar(50)
)
AS BEGIN
  UPDATE TABLENAME
  SET Name = @Name
  Where PrimaryKey = @PrimaryKey
END
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such help. But my issue is, the procedure I am using has multiple parameters. Actually I am updating the details of any contact person that belongs to a specific Vendor. Majorly, forwarding the name of contact person that is to be update in my db from .net is the issue. I don't know how to get that particular name from my data table.